# push down LI section

Tags: html, css

side menu bar works fine until I add class. please see example

### before

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/q44hu83e/)

### after

adding class="active" to `My Account Home`. `Demographics` `<LI>` completely pushed up and it is invisible. How can align like first pic like the order.

[image]
[After JSFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/q44hu83e/1/)

Comment: Please provide some code. Include your HTML and CSS.

Comment: You have issues with this before you added the class. As your fiddle currently is, where is the photo item that's supposed to appear under the active one?

Comment: It looks like the "active" class makes elements `position:absolute`, removing them from the document flow. As a result, the height of the `<ul>` that contains "My Account Home" is reduced to zero and the "Demographics" `<li>` moves up and is hidden behind "My Account Home".

Comment: @Huangism photo item?

Comment: @James123 After contact information, the next item is Photo but you can't see it because the active class has position absolute on it. You only noticed the issue when you added class because there was not another item under it

Comment: @Huangism, that is true. I observed now. looks `:after' is causing this issue. Any solution you have?

Comment: I don't have a full solution as your menu has a complex design, but you can start here http://jsfiddle.net/q44hu83e/2/

Comment: i fixed with your solution